# Error spliting NSarray into sections

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

Okay so I have been working through an example that closely matches what I am trying to achive, the sole difference being that in the example he is directly calling from his database the data he needs to be sectioned etc. Where as I already have a sorted NSArray.

This is the tutorial I am working off - [iPhone Development: Creating Native Contacts like screen](http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native.html)

I have created a Method that is capturing each entry in the NSArray and putting these results into a alpha based NSDictionary (so their will be a NSDictionary for A,B,C... etc)

here is my method.

```
//method to sort array and split for use with uitableview Index
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayData
{
    //Sort incoming array alphabetically
    //sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [self setSortedArray:[arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    arrayOfCharacters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    objectsForCharacters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(char c='A';c<='Z';c++)
    {

        if([sortedArray count] >0)
        {
            [arrayOfCharacters addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
            [objectsForCharacters setObject:sortedArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
            NSLog(@"%@", objectsForCharacters);
        }
        [sortedArray release];


    //Reloads data in table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This is putting every value into every alpha section, I am hoping someone can help me with making it so that only alpha sections are established if there is a value in the array for it.. then only loading those values into each section, not every section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code will do just that and will be much more efficient than filtering the array once for each letter.

```
//Sort incoming array alphabetically so that each sub-array will also be sorted.
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

// Dictionary will hold our sub-arrays
NSMutableDictionary *arraysByLetter = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Iterate over all the values in our sorted array
for (NSString *value in sortedArray) {

    // Get the first letter and its associated array from the dictionary.
    // If the dictionary does not exist create one and associate it with the letter.
    NSString *firstLetter = [value substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForLetter = [arraysByLetter objectForKey:firstLetter];
    if (arrayForLetter == nil) {
        arrayForLetter = [NSMutableArray array];
        [arraysByLetter setObject:arrayForLetter forKey:firstLetter];
    }

    // Add the value to the array for this letter
    [arrayForLetter addObject:value];
}

// arraysByLetter will contain the result you expect
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", arraysByLetter);
```

Note that arraysByLetter is a dictionary that contains one array per "first letter" that exists in your initial data.

--- Added on 2011-09-23 ---

```
[sortedArray removeAllObjects];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [arraysByLetter.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    [sortedArray addObject:key];
    [sortedArray addObjectsFromArray: [arraysByLetter objectForKey:key]];
}

NSLog(@"Sorted Array: %@", sortedArray);
```

The output is the following:

```
C,
Computer,
H,
Helene,
Hello,
J,
Jules,
W,
World
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks very much, I have been trying to sort this problem for the last 2 days :P

Comment: This has actually stopped me from being able to print out the resutls onto the uitabelviewcells.. not sure how to get the data from NSDictionary..

Comment: I'm guessing that your table was bound to the array. You might want to put the contents of the dictionary into that array. NSDictionary has a nice enumerator to do just that.

Comment: okay thank you I will look into how to do this.. telling you now that this whole experiance with indexing tableviews has been the biggest pain in my ass...lol

Comment: Hey man, just woundering if you know how to set the uitableviewcell with the NSDictionary values? I am trying to do it like so but the app is crashing on me when it tries to access the NSDictionary outside of this method.. This is what I am trying NSString *value = [self.arraysByLetter objectForKey:[[self.arraysByLetter allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = value;

Comment: I've updated the code to handle the transition from a dictionary to an array but I must say that this is a trivial step that you could have figured out by yourself.

Comment: yea thanks for that, I ended up getting your original code to work, however I am just stuck on trying to pass the NSDictionary values over to the UItableview cell textlabel.. as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509160/updated-cannot-pass-nsdictionary-to-uitableviewcell-textlabel thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: everything works fine up untill I count.. for some reason Im not getting the correct count value on either section or row. lol

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to filter `sortedArray` with a predicate for each letter. Something like this...

```
for(char c='A';c<='Z';c++) {
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] '%c'", c];
    NSArray *objectsBeginningWithCurrentLetter = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if([sortedArray count] >0)
    {
        [arrayOfCharacters addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
        if ([objectsBeginningWithCurrentLetter count] > 0) {
            [objectsForCharacters setObject:objectsBeginningWithCurrentLetter forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
            NSLog(@"%@", objectsForCharacters);
        }
    }
    [sortedArray release];


//Reloads data in table
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You may also want to check out [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) on sorting arrays using predicates if you need more clarification.

Comment: Okay cheers for that, going to have a read of your code now. thanks for the help.