# UPDATED: cannot pass NSDictionary to UITableViewCell textlabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

Updating this Thread as I have had some other help solving why I was not able to access the NSDictionarys values outside the method...

I was initalizing it wrong thus autorelease was being called at the end of the method so when I was calling it outside of that method I was getting all sorts of errors..

So now basically I am trying to allocate the NSDictionarys values to the UITableViewCell Text inside cellForRowAtIndexPath however I am getting this error

here is how I am trying to allocate it and the output at this point

```
// Configure the cell...
    if(indexPath.row <= [self.sectionLetters count]){

       // NSObject *key = [self.sectionLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *value = [self.arraysByLetter objectForKey:[self.sectionLetters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"thingy %@", value);

        cell.textLabel.text = value;
   }

    return cell;
```

.output

```
2011-09-23 10:25:01.343 Code[6796:207] thingy (
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda
)
```

however, if I comment out `//Cell.textLabel.text = value;` I get this output

.output2

```
2011-09-23 10:26:38.322 Code[6876:207] thingy (
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda,
    Honda
)
2011-09-23 10:26:38.323 Code[6876:207] thingy (
    Mazda,
    Mazda,
    Mitsubishi,
    Mitsubishi,
    Mitsubishi,
    Mitsubishi,
    Mitsubishi,
    Mitsubishi
)
2011-09-23 10:26:38.325 Code[6876:207] thingy (
    Nissan,
    Nissan,
    Nissan,
    Nissan,
    Nissan,
    Nissan,
    Nissan
)
2011-09-23 10:26:38.326 Code[6876:207] thingy (
    Toyota,
    Toyota,
    Toyota
)
```

Comment: Are you able to post your interface (.h) file?

Comment: Provide .h file show declaration of arraysByLetter. Thanks :)

Comment: I guess this requires asking... you're absolutely sure that startSortingTheArray is called BEFORE cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No its not... which I am thinking is obviously a real big issue... I am calling  [self.tableView reloadData]; inside my startSortingTheArray method...

Comment: But its still called at the end of the method. Don't see any issue there. Put breakpoint on where dictionay is set, and dictionary is accessed. See which one hits first. Also, why are your dictionary and array IBOutlet? :)

Comment: yea.. about that.. lol because Im stupid... if its not an outlet I just have to declear it like NSDictionary *mydic; aye?

Comment: Yeh IBOutlet are only for linking with Interface Builder elements (UITextFields, UILabels etc)

Comment: To my surprize its set in startSortingTheArray method before its accessed in my tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: So ... hmmm... which line is the error on?

Comment: I have updated code, the error happens at cellforrowatindexpath
// Configure the cell...
        NSString *value = [arraysByLetter objectForKey:[[arraysByLetter allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; <<<--This is where the error occurs...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3680/discussion-between-daryl-teo-and-c-johns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what, I think I know the problem so I'm going to make a guess.

Because you're using arraysByLetter directly, I don't believe you're hitting the synthesized properties, but the backing variable instead. You need to use self.arraysByLetter (this will retain the Dictionary).

At least, I've been using self.property forever, so I can't remember if this was a necessity or just a habit. Give that a shot.

Comment: arrrr!!! yes I think you might be right.. I tried using [self arraysByLetter] earlier but didnt work!!! what an idiot! thats how you call a method aye :P ill try it out now. fingers crossed.

Comment: [self arraysByLetter] is the getter.
if you want to use message sending use [self setArraysByLetter]