# How to create indexPath from NSArray of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

Okay I am trying to create an indexPath value from a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` values so that when I go through to my tableview I can place an accessory tick on the side.

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` that look like this

```
{
        HAS = 1;
        ISL = 1;
        ISV = 0;
        MAN = BANKING;
        MON = 324;
}
```

So the array would about 80 of these entries each with different values..

To create the IndexPath I would need to count the number of unique first letters of **MAN** until **MAN == selected String** This would give me the Section number.

Then I would need to count how many entries are in the selected section type for rows.

I have had some help already from here but I failed to identify a flaw in my logic.. for the row I was counting all of the entires instead of from the start of the selected section which ment my row count was totally stuffed. Below is a example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
a, aa, b, c, d, dd, ddd, dddd, e, f, g, gg
```

the user selects ddd so the indexpath would be

section

```
a, b, c, (d), e, f, g = 3
```

row

```
d, dd, (ddd), dddd = 2
```

I can get the section fine like so

```
NSArray *MANArray = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"MAN"];

NSMutableArray *letters = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *currentLetter = nil;
for (NSString *string in MANArray) {
    if (string.length > 0) {
        NSString *letter = [string substringToIndex:1];
        if (![letter isEqualToString:currentLetter]) {
            [letters addObject:letter];
            currentLetter = letter;
        }
    }
}
NSArray *firstLetterArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:letters];
int sectionCount = 0;
for(int i=0; i<[firstLetterArray count]; i++){
    if( [[firstLetterArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:completedStringLetter]){
        sectionCount = i;
        NSLog(@"%d", sectionCount);
    }
}
```

But I am just stuck when trying to get the row count from the selected section.

any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have done to count until the selected value but like I said its incorrect as it needs to start from the section depending on the first letter.

```
NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[modIdString integerValue]];

//                
NSArray *subarray = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"MOD"];
for(int i=0; i<[subarray count]; i++){
   if( [[subarray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToNumber:myNumber]){
      //you have found it, do whatever you need, and break from the loop
      modelResultIndexPath = nil;
      modelResultIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sectionCount inSection:i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about converting the array with values `"a, aa, b, c, d, dd, ddd, dddd, e, f, g, gg"` to an `NSDictionary` of arrays as,

```
dict = {
        a = [a, aa];
        b = [b];
        c = [c];
        d = [d, dd, ddd, dddd];
        e = [e];
        f = [f];
        g = [g, gg];
}
```

and then `[[dict allKeys] count]` should give you the section count and `[[dict valueForKey:@"d"] count]` should give the corresponding row count.

In order to convert the array to array of dictionaries, Use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466569/error-spliting-nsarray-into-sections?rq=1),

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSMutableDictionary *arraysByLetterDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *value in sortedArray) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [value substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    NSMutableArray *arrayForLetter = [arraysByLetterDict objectForKey:firstLetter];
    if (!arrayForLetter) {
        arrayForLetter = [NSMutableArray array];
        [arraysByLetterDict setObject:arrayForLetter forKey:firstLetter];
    }
    [arrayForLetter addObject:value];
}
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", arraysByLetterDict);
```

Indexpath can be calculated as,

```
NSArray *allKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
int totalSectionCount = [allKeys count];
int totalRowCount = [[dict valueForKey:@"d"] count];

int sectionCount = [allKeys indexOfObject:@"d"];
int rowCount = [[dict valueForKey:@"d"] indexOfObject:@"ddd"];

modelResultIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowCount inSection:sectionCount];
```

Comment: Since dictionary keys are unsorted you will run into an issue with getting sectionCount. To use this approach you will also need to maintain an ordered list of the keys (like the original code) or use a custom dictionary class that maintains the order.

Comment: going to try this out now.. I have already sorted the array of dictionaries so this should hopefully work.

Comment: @HurkNburkS, I have checked with the array string in your question and it looked to me like working. Check it and let me know.

Comment: @HurkNburkS, section count and row count for "ddd" should be calculated as,  int sectionCount = [[dict allKeys] indexOfObject:@"d"];
int rowCount = [[dict valueForKey:@"d"] indexOfObject:@"ddd"]; Corrected my answer. totalSectionCount and totalRowCount can be used to draw the table with sections and rows inside that.

Comment: This is super close to working.. but its just giving me a slightly incorect row count.. I think maybe its starting from 1 or something.. instead of 0.. just trying to track it down atm.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. As per the "a, aa, b, c, d, dd, ddd, dddd, e, f, g, gg", it should have given 2 for ddd as row count. Is there anything else different?

Comment: no it seems to work.. im just working through it properly now.. every thing appears fine.. so just debugging it.. I feel like its going to work though :P will keep you informed.

Comment: I have tried just selecting a so I should get a indexpath of [0, 0] but I actually get [3, 0].. not sure why.

Comment: Probably you might have to sort the [dict allKeys] array before doing int sectionCount = [[dict allKeys] indexOfObject:@"d"]; Check with my updated answer.

Comment: dont listen to me it is the section count stuffing up.. so usless.. if you log a Indexpath its [Section, Row] but if you created one its [Row, Section] ... messing with my MIND!.. still working on it

Comment: Have you tried with the updated answer?NSArray *allKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
int sectionCount = [allKeys indexOfObject:@"d"];
int rowCount = [[dict valueForKey:@"d"] indexOfObject:@"ddd"];

Comment: WHOOP WHOOP!!! it worked, ledgend thank you very very much! now... time to clean up my code LOL.. just so you know I used your last comment to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I knew that, that was the issue when you said you got 3 instead of 0.

Comment: lol.. i had no idea.. man i have debugged the hell out of my code... LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predicate on the original array of dictionaries to filter out all the dictionaries that begin with a particular letter, and then find the index of the matching one you are looking for using idexOfObjectPassingTest:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.MAN beginswith[c] '%@'", SELECTED_FIRST_LETTER_OF_MAN];
NSArray *filteredDictionaries = [sortedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
int rowCount = [filteredDictionaries indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)obj;

    if ([dictionary[@"MAN"] isEqualToString:SELECTED_MAN]
        && [dictionary[@"MON"] isEqualToString:SELECTED_MON]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}];
```

Comment: ahh.. okay going to have a play will come back and mark your answer once i get it going.

Comment: okay.. my fault I forgot MAN can have multiple instances that are identical.. the way to tell them apart is by using MON as its unique identifier... Painful I know. I have updated my question with the function I have created to count up till the selected value

Comment: you can concatenate MAN+MON and create an array of those string. Then filter that using the same predicate above.

Comment: What about somehow creating an array of dictionaries instead of just an array for filteredWords? would you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I am still trying to work on this.. for some reason I dont think I'm doing the predicate properly as when I filter the dictionaries I have zero objects in the Array... hrmm or maybe it should be a mutable array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using two arrays with parallel structure.
Here's my code for generating the indexPath in one to use in the other:

```
    var sectionCounter = 0
    var itemsCounter = 0
    stopIdsArray.map({
        $0.map( {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item:itemsCounter,section:sectionCounter)
            NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getData(stop:$0,indexPath:indexPath)
            itemsCounter += 1
        })
        itemsCounter = 0
        sectionCounter += 1
    })
```